# DialogFragment set height of Dialog

Tags: android, android-dialogfragment

I just used created by first Dialog using DialogFragment.
Everything works great except I can't get the Dialog to wrap it's layout.
My layout has the height of all elements to `wrap_content`.

In `MyFragmentDialog` I can't even find a method that would imply that it can be used to set the height of the `FragmentDialog`. What am I missing? How do I make a DialogFragment fit it's content?

**The `DialogFrament`'s `onCreateView` method:**

```
    @Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Set title for this dialog
    getDialog().setTitle("Backup & Restore");
    getDialog().setCancelable(true);

    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.backup_restore, container, false);
    TextView msg = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.br_label_message);
    msg.setText("Backups are placed in the Downloads Directory:\n" + BACKUP_PATH.getAbsolutePath());
    // TextView files_label = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.label_restore);
    Spinner files = (Spinner) v.findViewById(R.id.br_restore_file);

    if (BACKUP_PATH.exists()) {
        FilenameFilter filter = new FilenameFilter() {
            public boolean accept(File dir, String filename) {
                File sel = new File(dir, filename);
                return filename.contains(FTYPE) || sel.isDirectory();
            }
        };
        mFileList = BACKUP_PATH.list(filter);
    } else {
        mFileList = new String[0];
    }

    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<CharSequence>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, mFileList);
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    files.setAdapter(adapter);
    files.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);

    Button backup = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.br_backup_btn);
    Button restore = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.br_restore_btn);
    Button cancel = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.br_cancel_btn);

    backup.setOnClickListener(this);
    restore.setOnClickListener(this);
    cancel.setOnClickListener(this);

    return v;
}
```

**This is the layout:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="8dp" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/br_label_message"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingBottom="8dp"
        android:text=""
        android:textSize="14sp" />

    <TableLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/br_tableRow1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/br_label_restore"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingRight="8dp"
                android:text="Restore file"
                android:textSize="14sp" />

            <Spinner
                android:id="@+id/br_restore_file"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>

    <TableLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TableRow>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/br_restore_btn"
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight=".5"
                android:text="Restore"
                android:textSize="14sp" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/br_backup_btn"
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight=".5"
                android:text="Backup"
                android:textSize="14sp" />
        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/br_cancel_btn"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Cancel"
        android:textSize="14sp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 29, accepted):

It turns out to be an issue with `LinearLayout` despite setting a height on it, in `DialogFragment` it seems to be taking more space than I want it to. I switched layout to be a `RelativeLayout` the content `Dialog` seems to resize to fit the content.

Comment: hey can u post the solution? did u set height for relative layout or wrap_content?

Comment: width was `match_parent`, height was `wrap_content`. Let me know if you still need me to post the solution.

Comment: Thanks Ali.i made a work around.i wrapped the existing layout with a Relative Layout whose width and height are match_parent.Sure,u can post the answer which will be useful for others,if needed.

Comment: If you use Relative Layout you can't use the align parent bottom, align parent top etc. All the items must be above or below other items. As soon as you align to the parent top or bottom it will grow to fill the screen

Comment: @Kevin that is correct, however it wasn't really a problem for my use case.

Comment: Its just requires the RelativeLayout to be parent. You can take a linearlayout inside the relative and wrap your contents if you need to use linearlayout.

Comment: @ali please refer to this question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45494644/how-to-set-the-height-of-the-dialog-fragment-accurately-in-android

Answer (score 6):

You can make it work with all kind of layout in adding the size of the layout in the onResume of your dialogFragment :

```
  @Override
    public void onResume()
    {
        super.onResume();
        Window window = getDialog().getWindow();
        window.setLayout(300, 300);
        window.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
}
```

Comment: Out of the 100s of solutions I've found on SO for this stupid problem, this is the one that worked and kept me sane one more day.

Comment: @Gyome please refer to this question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45494644/how-to-set-the-height-of-the-dialog-fragment-accurately-in-android

Answer (score 4):

I took a leap into the Dialog api so I am certainly not sure but you could try to call getWindow on the dialog and then call setLayout(width, height)

```
getDialog().getWindow().setLayout(300,300);
```

Comment: Thanks Bram, but it turns out to be an issue with `LinearLayout` I switched it to a `RelativeLayout` and the content `Dialog` seems to resize to fit content.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see the top portion of your LinearLayout tag, but I've seen cases where all that was needed was the

```
android:orientation="vertical"
```

XML attribute. It can cause a headache but is fortunately easy to fix.