# Dialogue Fragment Wrap Content Via Height and Width

Tags: android, xml, android-fragments, android-dialogfragment

I am designing a fragment layout for the edit and delete button. But when i launch the fragment, its showing the full fragment. I want to wrap the dialogue fragment via height and width.
Here is the XML

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/start_app_background_image"
tools:context="com.example.mudasir.fitnessapp.fragments.DialogueFragmentMoreOptions"
android:orientation="vertical">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/edit_text"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
    android:text="Edit"
    android:textColor="@color/default_text_color"
    android:textSize="30dp" />

<View
    android:id="@+id/line"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="1dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/edit_text"
    android:background="@color/default_text_color"></View>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/delete_text"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/line"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"

    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
    android:text="Delete"
    android:textColor="@color/default_text_color"
    android:textSize="30dp" />
```

[image: What its looks like]

[image: What i want]

Comment: Your root **LinearLayout** is set to match parent, could you elaborate what do you mean by *"wrap the dialogue fragment via height and width"*?

Comment: Uploading the Images.

Comment: When i give wrap content, nothing happens

Comment: Could you try **RelativeLayout** instead of **LinearLayout** as suggested [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8958124/dialogfragment-set-height-of-dialog)?

Comment: Already tried RelativeLayout.. No affect..

Comment: Then it's probably caused by the dialog fragment style definition in the theme.